# Flex text flow cursor position

Tags: apache-flex

I am using `textFlow` with "rightToLeft" text: _textInputFlow.direction = "rtl";

The cursor is always on the left of the text. How I can set it always on the right of the text?

Vladimir

Comment: See this SO Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502414/how-do-you-programmatically-move-the-caret-of-a-flex-textarea-to-the-end